# Difference between numbers.length and normal forloop

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently new to java programming, and recently my teacher has given me some practice questions to do. In some of the `for` loop array questions, there are certain times where they use e.g

```
  for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
```

and at certain times they use this

```
 (for int j=0;j<7;j++)
```

Whats the difference?

Comment: what is numbers? an array? The question is incomplete and need more information

Answer (score 1):

1.)    `for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)`

Loop Starts from `j=0`

loop continues while `j<numbers.length`

This looping is actually defined at runtime, depending on the size of `numbers` array.

2.)    `for (int j=0;j<7;j++)`

Loop Starts from `j=0`

loop continues while `j<7`

> This is something we have fixed a count for looping, it will run 7
>   times provided there is no break statements, resetting
>   value of variable j, or any exception scenario.

Follow 1st when you don't know what is the size of the `array, list` or how many times you have to loop.

Follow 2nd, when looping fixed.

Comment: another thing to watch for is if you are adding or removing items from the array in the forloop function, the j<7 version could either not traverse the whole array, or throw an error if length of the array becomes less than 7.

Comment: ... loop continues *until* j<numbers.length ? Really? I think you may mean *while.* Ditto for the second case as well.

Comment: "until" is incorrect - you mean "while". Also note that the body can contain `break` statements, or modify the value of `i` or `j`, so the second loop won't definitely run 7 times...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes correct, but as per understanding from question and considering OP exp. in programming, seems he just wants to know the diff b/w the two.

Comment: @ankur-singhal: Yes, but I don't think claiming that the "looping is defined at compile time" helps that, given that it might not execute 7 times. (Of course an exception could be thrown too, and that may well depend on the data.) I just don't see any benefit in making those pretty strong claims...

Answer (score 1):

The form:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
```

tends to be used when you don't know at compile time how many items will be in the collection.

It runs `j` from `0` to `numbers.length - 1` inclusive and is generally used for processing the entire collection (by index) one by one.

On the other hand:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
```

will *always* execute seven times (assuming no "weirdness" like `break` or changing `j` within the loop, of course) - the `j` variable will range between `0` and `7` inclusive.

For a variable-sized collection, this is pretty much useless, and tends to be used for things that have a fixed size at compile time. Note that this *doesn't* include arrays where you dictate how much of the array you use with another variable. While an array itself is fixed size, imposition of a variable length on it in this way makes the data structure a variable sized one.

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamic `length` calculation

```
for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
```

Here loop will work upto when `j` will less than `length` of `numbers` and `numbers` is `Array` here.

While this is hard coded one

```
(for int j=0;j<7;j++)
```

Here you can see

`length` --- `arrays (int[], double[], String[])` ---- to know the length of the arrys.

`length()` --- `String` related Object (`String`, `StringBuilder` etc)to know the length of the `String`

Answer (score 0):

`numbers.length` will give you the length of array and the loop continues until the length .

but in the case of 7 the loop will be end after 7 iteration .